# How to add fontawesome to angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I have an issue. I intall font-awesome by npm like this
`npm install --save font-awesome`
and later I add a style to :
`

```
"apps": [
    {
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
      ]
    }
```

`
but it don't work in my app.
Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to add this to my project? 
I also try by ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello to my dear friend there is two way for it one of them is using `angular-font-awesome` and the other one is that you must go to `angular-cli.json` and add this

`"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
],`

but if you want to use `angular-font-awesome` you can use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome)